# Casting a LINQ date to a DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I'm trying to get a list of all of the UIDs from this XML where the date is more than 6 months ago:

```
<Photos>
  <Photo UID="b68552e32a4f47f592fb737adf305a4d">
    <Date>2014-01-22T10:20:09.078873+01:00</Date>
    <File>b68552e32a4f47f592fb737adf305a4d.JPG</File>
  </Photo>
  <Photo UID="2802f727a8c74e15ae8fe20dbd0d7137">
    <Date>2013-08-22T10:20:10.278873+01:00</Date>
    <File>2802f727a8c74e15ae8fe20dbd0d7137.JPG</File>
  </Photo>
  <Photo UID="dd51105cf6ca4bd88a6a2f521d935ea7">
    <Date>2014-08-22T10:20:33.998873+01:00</Date>
    <File>dd51105cf6ca4bd88a6a2f521d935ea7.JPG</File>
  </Photo>
</Photos>
```

I'm using the following LINQ code:

```
var fileList = xml.Descendants("Photo")
       .Where(e => e.Attribute("Date") < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
       .Select("UID")
       .ToList();
```

However, it says it cannot compare the two variables in the where clause, so I tried using a cast with no joy, and eventually trying a `DateTime.Parse`:

```
.Where(e => DateTime.Parse(e.Attribute("Date")) < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
```

But I get an error saying that `DateTime.Parse()` has some invalid arguments.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong please?

Many thanks

Comment: is e.Attribute("Date") returning a string?

Comment: Read the second error message.

Comment: e.Attribute("Date") returns the xAttribute Date, e.Attribute("Date").Value would have made your original code work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code using [XmlConvert.ToDateTime Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shd19e3h(v=vs.110).aspx) :-

```
IEnumerable<Guid> uids = xml.Descendants("Photo")
   .Where(e => XmlConvert.ToDateTime(e.Element("Date").Value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc) < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
       .Select(e => Guid.Parse(e.Attribute("UID").Value))
       .ToList();
```

Comment: `DateTime.Parse()` works fine with the date format that OP has. The problem is that he was passing an `XAttribute` to it.

Comment: Thank you Neel, this works perfectly :) Is IEnumerable better than using a list like I was before? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Date isn't an attribute but a node, you want /Photo/Date not /Photo[@Date]

Also use XMLConvert.ToDate and that will safely unpack the value back to a datetime.

```
xml.Descendants("Photo").Where(e => XmlConvert.ToDateTime(e.Element("Date").Value, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc) < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a couple of other problems too (ie my select statement) but this is a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute method returns `XAttribute`, not `string`. In order to obtain it's value, you need to use `Value` property.

```
var fileList = xml.Descendants("Photo")
       .Where(e => DateTime.Parse(e.Attribute("Date").Value) < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
       .Select("UID")
       .ToList();
```

Comment: `ToString()` is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you! I had a couple of other problems too (ie my select statement) but this is a good answer.

Comment: @Nick Sorry, I have just CtrlC_CtrlV_ed your code above :)

Comment: Really no need to apologise, it was some very bad coding by me! Thanks again for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
.Where(e => DateTime.Parse((string)e.Element("Date")) < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-6))
.Select(e => Guid.Parse((string)e.Attribute("UID")))
.ToList()
```

Note that `Date` is an element, not an attribute.

Comment: Reason for downvote, please? Of all the answers provided, this is the most concise one that actually works.

Comment: Thank you JLR, unfortunately when trying this I get an error: `The type arguements for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select' cannot be inferred from the usage. I'm not sure about the downvote though, the Element/Attribute was a really good catch, thank you.

Comment: @Nick There was a problem with the `Select` part in your original code. I've now added a fix above.

Comment: Thank you, good spot, and sorry I only just noticed that after I posted (I really need to brush up on my LINQ!) - thanks again